# Returning combined arrays from observable query from Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I want to run 'OR' query on firestore collection while fetching and get combined array to iterate over. Nothing is being shown from firestore or shown as 
   * []
   * []

I have tried getting valuechanges with where query on two params of firestore collection fields and then use 'combineLatest' to join.

Firestore collection 'DATAS':

```
{
   parent_title: 'Hello',
   title: 'Mello'
}
```

And want to fetch from firestore:
    import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

```
datas1 = this._afs.collection('DATAS', ref => ref.where('title','==', 
'Hello')).valueChanges();
datas2 = this._afs.collection('DATAS', ref => 
ref.where('parent_title','==', 'Hello')).valueChanges();
data = combineLatest(datas1, data2);
```

in HTML,

```
<li *ngFor = 'let item of data | async'>
      {{ item | json }}
</li>
```

I want to have joined results of OR queries